# Kac Lemma for staionary ergodic processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, information-theory, ergodic-theory

Simple question. I have a stationary ergodic process $U$ on a finite alphaet and I want to prove the Kac's Lemma (see Cover and Thomas - *Elements of Information Theory* (second ed.) page 445).

In the proof there is
$$A_{jk}:=\{ U_{-j}=u,U_{k}=u,U_{i}\neq u \, for \, -j<i<k\}$$
where U is the process, u is a fixed character, and j,i, k are integer.
There yields that the probability of the union on all j and k is 1 by ergodicity, but I really cannot see why.

Probably my problem is that I do not have a clear idea about what an ergodic stochastic process is, so any kind of help in this sense is much appreciated.

Thank you!

(Sorry for my poor English!)

Comment: Please include more context/details for your question. Most people probably don't have that text at hand to refer to...

Comment: I just edited the question. Now all that you read should be defined. Sorry!

Comment: I think you mean the union of all sets $A_{jk}$ for $j,k$ such that $-j<k$. This union is the event that the character $u$ eventually is seen twice. If $u$ has a positive ergodic probability $p$, then (by ergodicity) the fraction of time it is seen in an interval of size $t$ converges to $p$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$ (so $N(t)/t\rightarrow p$ with prob 1, where $N(t)$ is the number of times $u$ is seen up to slot $t$).  So, with prob 1,  it will be seen an infinite number of times (almost surely at least 2 times).

Comment: Yes, I mean that with $k\geq 0$ and $j > 0$. Thank you, @Michael