# Kac Lemma for Ergodic Stationary Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, information-theory, ergodic-theory

I know [it was asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330726/kac-lemma-for-staionary-ergodic-processes), but I still don't understand the answers in the post and I think I am missing some key arguments to understand but not sure which. 
I am reading Cover and Thomas
["Elements of information theory"](http://coltech.vnu.edu.vn/~thainp/books/Wiley_-_2006_-_Elements_of_Information_Theory_2nd_Ed.pdf),
and on page 445 the author prooves Kac Lemma. First we got a

> Let $\{ U_{i} \}_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be a stationary ergodic process on a countable alphabet. for any $u$ s.t $p(u)>0$

next, in the beginning of the proof:

> define the event: 
>   for $j=1, 2, 3, ...$ and $k = 0, 1, 2, ... $ 
>   $A_{jk} := \{U_{-j}=u, U_{l} \neq u \ \forall -j<l<k, U_{k}=u\}$

in the following sentence the author writes

> by ergodicity, the probability $Pr(\cup_{j,k}A_{jk})=1$

now, for the last day I tried to prove this claim using stationary egrodic process properties. I must say that this is for a course in information theory and not ergodic theory (which I never learned), but we had a couple of lessons about ergodicity especially in the light of stationary stochastic processes. 
My attemp so far was to try a rewrite $A_{jk} =: [uLu]_{-j}^k$ so if $T: X^{\mathbb{Z}}\rightarrow X^{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the trasformation defined as $\pi_i(T(x))=x_{i+1}$ ($\pi_i$ is the projection of the i-th' coordinate, so T is the left shift transformation), since the process is stationary ergodic, T is ergodic and $T([uLu]_{-j}^k)=[uLu]_{-j-1}^{k-1}$ and $T^{-1}([uLu]_{-j}^k)=[uLu]_{-j+1}^{k+1}$.
So after trying playing with the [definition of ergodicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodicity) on those sets in order to prove $Pr(\cup_{jk}A_{jk})=1$ I understand I am missing something clearly. Is it part of my definitions of stochastic stationary ergodic process? Or it's actually a hard-try to prove with simple tools? or I'm just missing something simple?! 

Thanks.

Comment: Your notation $[ulu]^k_{-j}$ doesn't seem appropriate: $u$ is an element of the alphabet, $l$ is a running index.

Comment: A stationary process translates to a shift transformation $T:X^\mathbb{Z}\to X^\mathbb{Z}$ AND a probability measure on $X^\mathbb{Z}$ that is invariant under $T$.  Let us call that measure $\mu$.  Try writing down the definition of ergodicity for $T$ with invariant measure $\mu$.  Then, try to translate that back to see what it says about the process $\{U_i\}$.

Comment: @Blackbird you are right about the notations. it should write as $L$ instead of l. If i'm correct $\mu$ is exactly $p$. so for example $\mu(u) = p(u)$. Right?

Comment: This is the same question proved in a general setting. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300302/lifting-back-the-induced-invariant-measure-general-version-of-kacs-formula-fo/308720